# Merge all the columns value into one column as CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, clrstoredprocedure

How can I combine all the values of the row into one single field in **MS SQL Server**,

Suppose my table format is ::

```
area_name || city || state || postal_code || country || address
```

Output

```
area||city||state||postal_code||country||

area,city,state,postal_code,country
```

How to merge the values of area_name, city, state, postal_code and country to make one address in CSV format.

My code

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[p_insert_address]
    @ID             INT = 0,
    @area_name      VARCHAR(20)
    @city           VARCHAR(20),
    @state          VARCHAR(20),
    @postal_code    VARCHAR(20),
    @country        VARCHAR(20) 
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;     

            INSERT INTO address (@area_name, city, state, postal_code, country)
            VALUES (@area_name, @city, @state, @postal_code, @country);     

        SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    END
```

Comment: Do you want to select them as csv or insert then as csv to the table?

Answer (score 0):

This to insert data in your table:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[p_insert_address]
    @ID             INT = 0,
    @area_name      VARCHAR(20)
    @city           VARCHAR(20),
    @state          VARCHAR(20),
    @postal_code    VARCHAR(20),
    @country        VARCHAR(20) 
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;     

            INSERT INTO address (area_name, city, state, postal_code, country,csv)
            VALUES (@area_name, @city, @state, @postal_code, @country, @area_name+','+@city+','+@state+','+@postal_code+','+@country);     

        SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    END
```

Otherwise:

```
SELECT area_name, city, state, postal_code, country,area_name+','+city+','+state+','+postal_code+','+country
FROM address
```

Comment: update is not working, no error but not giving output also. here is the code :: `update address 
set csv = area_name+','+city+','+state+','+postal_code+','+country` can not update csv field.

Comment: There was no update, so if you call the procedure with same data it is just inserting a new row, unless you have some unique constraint on your table. I didn't know you needed an update; however it was quite easy to get it from the insert code

Comment: yes I tried the same from Insert code but not working.

Comment: Excuse me but i do not understand your last comment